# React native - cross platform with windows phone

Tags: react-native, windows-phone, cross-platform, windows-10-mobile

Is React Native made for windows phone too?
If no what is best language or tool that is worth learning in mobile app cross-platform development?

Comment: Yes, it is [available](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows) for UWP and WPF. The second part of your question is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native doesn't come with support for Windows Phone (7/8/8.1).

Microsoft has created a really good React Native plugin for [Windows Phone's successor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone#Versions): Windows 10 Mobile, but they also announced that the company [no longer focuses on the platform](https://www.cnet.com/news/windows-10-mobile-features-hardware-death-sentence-microsoft/) so choose wisely.

React Native Windows plugin repository:
https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows